# AWS Pipeline, wait for stage to complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, pipeline

I have a AWS pipeline, which:

1) first stage, get template.yaml and build a ec2 windows instance via script

- note when this machine boots up, via user data it starts a script to downloads requirements, git etc, code, setups iis and various other stuff.
  so this happens once the cloudformation part has completed, and takes about another 5 mins

2) i then want to run external tests on this machine - maybe using blazemeter, as the second part of the pipeline

the problem is that between stage 1 and 2 i need to wait for the website to work on the box, so i need to wait at least 5 mins. i could add a manual approval stage, but this seams cumbersome.

does anyone have a way to add this timed wait? or a pipeline process to check the site is up?